# Problems referencing root in Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, rspec-rails

I am trying to test if a users input is valid using Capybara. I am following https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec and am having problems with referencing the root. As you can see in my rails_helper I have already included config.includeRails.application.routes.url_helpers. This should give me access to the appropriate helper methods right? Any help would be much appreciated.

console error

```
Failure/Error: visit root

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserInputsPhonenumber:0x007fce5abaa970>
```

user_inputs_phone_number_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
feature 'User inputs phonenumber' do 
    it 'returns sent if valid input', :js=>true do
        visit root
        within('.intl-tel-input allow-dropdown') do 
            fill_in 'phone', :with => 'xxxxxxxxxx'
        end
        click_button 'submit-btn' 
        expect(page).to have_content 'Sent!'
    end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# ruby "2.2.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Added to rails
gem 'mixpanel-ruby', '~> 2.2'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.11', '>= 4.11.1'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.11', '>= 2.11.1'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use remote_syslog_logger gem to send logs to sumologic
gem 'remote_syslog_logger'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rubygems'
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  # config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # This allows you to limit a spec run to individual examples or groups
  # you care about by tagging them with `:focus` metadata. When nothing
  # is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run. RSpec also provides
  # aliases for `it`, `describe`, and `context` that include `:focus`
  # metadata: `fit`, `fdescribe` and `fcontext`, respectively.
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end

Capybara.configure do |c|
  c.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'download' => 'invites#show', constraints: { subdomain: 'come' }

  # welcome
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'dl' => 'welcome#download'
  get 'download' => 'welcome#download'
  get 'send_invite' => 'welcome#send_invite'
  get 'intern' => 'welcome#intern'
  get '/apple-app-site-association' => 'welcome#apple_app_site_association'

  # invites
  get '/i/:k' => 'invites#show'
  get 'invite/:title/:k' => 'invites#show_share'
  get 'update_invite/:invite_key/:phone/:first/:last/:iso_code' => 'invites#update'

  # lists
  get 'list/:list_name/:list_key' => 'welcome#share_list'
  get 'lists/:list_name/:list_key' => 'welcome#share_list'
  get 'list/:list_key' => 'welcome#share_list'
  get 'update_list/:list_key/:phone/:first/:last/:iso_code' => 'welcome#add_shared_list'

  # healthchecks
  get 'healthcheck-app' => 'welcome#healthcheck_app'
  get 'healthcheck-all' => 'welcome#healthcheck_all'

  # policy pages
  get 'privacy-policy' => 'welcome#privacy_policy'
  get 'terms' => 'welcome#terms'
  get 'download-agreement' => 'welcome#download_agreement'
end
```

Edit

After adding include 'rails_helper' to the top of my spec. I get an error of `/Users/jacobshafi/Desktop/Code/web/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:7:in`block in ': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

environment_variables.rb

```
module EnvironmentVariablesExample
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_configuration do
      env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'environment_variables.yml').to_s

      if File.exists?(env_file)
        YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
          ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end # end YAML.load_file
      end # end if File.exists?
    end # end config.before_configuration
  end # end class
end # end module
```

Comment: did you try root_path?

Comment: Yes I did. Same error message occurs.

Comment: WHat about require 'rails_helper' at the top instead of spec_helper.

Comment: I have tried that actually. When I try require 'rails_helper' I get an error message of /config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:7:in `block in <class:Application>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).

Comment: One more thing I see missing in what I usually do (i admit to being what I calla an intermediate beginner which is why i'm doing comments not answers) but you just state 'feature. and I usually start RSpec.feature - for example - here's the top two lines of something i'm working on at this moment  `require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Creating Kegs" do`

Comment: No worries! Any help is much appreciated. So I have tried what you recommended and because I get an error when requiring 'rails_helper' am not including it. If I try your recommendation with require 'spec_helper' I get an error of uninitialized constant Rspec (NameError).

Comment: You need to use `root_path`, not `root`.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my config. my rails_helper and spec_helper files should be helping me with my configuration but it doesn't seem to be working the way I expect it to.

Comment: Jacob - at least when you use rails_helper you get a *specific* error - use Rails_helper and then look at the line it references and see if you can find an answer  BTW - I only ever put RSpec into the testing development - not development

Comment: @infused where do I need to be using root_path?

Comment: `visit root` should be `visit root_path`

Comment: @infused that was the first comment

Comment: So update your question then.  This isnt a support forum.

Comment: @infused - oh so you're one of those unhelpful non welcoming people - you didn't read the comments before contributing your suggestion so then you get upset about it.  STackoverflow is a great idea but it's overly populated by bombastic people more worried about rules than helping

Comment: No, I'm saying update your question with the actual error you are getting and the code where the error actually occurs. You're making it difficult for people to help you otherwise.

Comment: @infused I have updated the question. Thanks in advanced for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling

```
visit root_path
```

and you should be requiring rails_helper, rather than spec_helper. since rails_helper is where the url helpers get included -  'config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers'.  To fix the error you get from doing that we'd need to see the contents of config/initializers/environment_variables.rb

Comment: I have included edits to the question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JacobShafi That error would tend to imply you don't have a test: section in your environment_variables.yml file  - which would mean YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env] ends up returning nil -- add a test: section (assuming you're running tests in the 'test' environment) and the error will be fixed

Comment: @TomWalope That worked so perfectly! Thank you so much! Still having some errors but I know exactly where they are coming from.

Comment: @JacobShafi You're welcome - don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.